# Itō Integral has expectation zero

Tags: stochastic-integrals, stochastic-calculus

I have a question about the following property, which I didn't know so far:

> Why does the Itō integral have zero expectation? Is this true for every integrator and integrand? Or is this restricted to special processes, i.e. is
>   $$\mathbb{E}\left[\int f \, \mathrm{d}M\right]=0$$
>   for all local Martingales $M$ and predictable $f$, such that the integral is well defined?

Thank you for clarification.

Comment: Ito Integral is  a martingale.

Answer (score 39):

This statement is wrong in general.

It may fail even when the integrator $M_t$ is a Brownian motion. In fact,

> Given a probability distribution $P$ on $\mathbb{R}$, it is possible
>   to find an adapted $t$-measurable process $f(\omega,t)$, with
>   $\mathbb{P}\left(\int_0^1 f^2(\omega,t)\,dt<\infty\right)=1$ such
>   that the random variable $$\int_0^1 f(\omega,t) \, dB_t$$ has
>   distribution $P$.

This statement is known as Dudley's representation theorem (see the [original paper](http://dx.doi.org/doi:10.1214/aop/1176995898)). Hence, the expectation of the stochastic integral may take any real value, be infinite or not exist at all.

---

Another counterexample arises from the stochastic differential equation $$dX_t = X^2_t\, dB_t, \quad X_0=x, \quad \textrm{where } x>0.$$
It may be shown that the solution exists, is unique, is a strictly positive local martingale, but $\mathbb{E} X_t \to 0$ as $t\to \infty$.
See the details in George Lowther's [blog](http://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/failure-of-the-martingale-property/), where this example is taken from.

---

A sufficient condition for the integral $\int_0^t f(\omega, s)\, dB_s$ to be a martingale on $[0,T]$ is that

1. $f(\omega,s)$ is adapted, measurable in s, *and*
2. $\mathbb{E}\left(\int_0^T f^2(\omega,s)\,ds\right) < \infty$.

In this case, indeed, $\mathsf{E} \left(\int_0^T f(\omega,s)\, dB_s\right)=0$.

---

If the integrator $M_t$ is an arbitrary martingale, and the integrand $f$ is bounded, then the integral is a martingale, and the expectation of the integral is again zero ([proof](http://almostsure.wordpress.com/2009/12/06/martingales-and-elementary-integrals/#scn_mart_lem2)).

---

Finally, if the integrator $M_t$ is a *local* martingale, very little can be said about the expectation of the integral. If $f(\omega,t)$ is sufficiently nice, the integral $\int_0^t f(\omega,s) \, dM_s$ is a local martingale, but that does not guarantee that the expectation is zero, as the second counterexample above shows.

Answer (score 5):

Intuitive answer: for an Ito integral with respect to Brownian motion (and nice enough $f$), $\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t f(B_s) dB_s\right] = 0$ because each little $dB$ has mean zero - in fact, has distribution that is symmetric about zero (and, independent of where $B$ is!).  You can think of the integral, just like a normal integral, as a weighted sum of lots of little $dB$'s; and the fact that you multiply them by a factor doesn't change the fact that their mean is zero. The fact that's being used here is exactly the martingale property.

[EDIT:] But, as pointed out by others, this intuitive answer does not necessarily hold: the Ito integral might turn out to be only a local martingale, not a martingale.  However, being a local martingale means it has mean zero "locally": see [the definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_martingale).

As for a more general statement: in Kallenberg (15.12) I find that if $M$ is a continuous local martingale with (finite) quadratic variation process $[M]$, and $V$ is a progressive process (implies predictable) with $\mathbb{E}[\int_0^t V^2_s d[M]_s] < \infty$ for all $t>0$, then $N_t = \int_0^t V_s dM_s$ is a continuous local martingale. If this is a martingale, then $\mathbb{E}[N_t]=0$ for all $t>0$.  Since in general it's only a local martingale, instead there is a sequence of increasing stopping times $\tau_k$ tending to $\infty$ such that $\mathbb{E}[N_{\min(t,\tau_k)}] = 0$ for each $k$.

Comment: It is not clear to me why that would be so unless $f$ is constant. To be concrete, imagine that the taxman takes a cut of your gambling earnings but doesn't refund your losses. Then the integral would not be a martingale, would it?

Comment: @pait :  First, the taxman example doesn't work, since that's an integral against $dt$, not $dB_t$.  Second, if you are convinced about constant functions, are you convinced about piecewise constant functions?  If so, then, take limits of such to get it for arbitrary $f$ -- this is one way the theorem can be proved.

Comment: The fact that $N_t$ is a continuous local martingale does not imply that its expectation is zero.

Comment: oops, yep. fixed.