# Is expectation of an Ito integral always 0, regardless of the limits?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I'm very sorry if this question sounds very basic, as I just started learning stochastic calculus. I found this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232932/it%C5%8D-integral-has-expectation-zero) and I would like to clarify whether the following always holds:

$$\mathbb{E}[\int_a^b B_s dB_s] = 0$$

where $a$ and $b$ can be any real number, and $B_s$ is a Standard Brownian Motion. So far, almost all examples I have seen sets $a=0$.

Comment: Yes, because the Ito integral always produces a martingale, for sufficiently nice integrands.

Comment: Based on the other link, you may find it helpful to write $\int_a^b B_s\,dB_s = \int_0^b B_s\,dB_s - \int_0^a B_s\,dB_s$ and use linearity of expectation.

Comment: @NateEldredge Ahhh goodness, why didn't I think of that...I really look like a fool for asking this ><...Thank you so much