# $\mathbb{E}[(\int_{0}^{t} V_s^2: d\langle M^{c}\rangle_{s})^{\frac{1}{2}}]<\infty$ implies $N_t:= \int_0^t V_s \cdot d M_{s}^{c}$ is a martingale.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, quadratic-variation

Suppose that $M$ is a continuous martingale and $V_s$ is a progressive process with $\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\int_{0}^{t} Tr(V_sV_s^T d\left\langle M\right\rangle_{s})\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right]<\infty$.

Show that $N_t:= \int_0^t V_s \cdot d M_{s}$ is a martingale.

I found a similar statement [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/402651), but I have no idea how to show this. Holder's inequality doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your notations are rather unclear... what mean I guess $V_s\in \mathbb R^n$. Then, what mean $V_s^2\cdot dM_s$ ? Moreover, what means $V_s^2:\,\mathrm d M_s$ (for me $V_s^2=V_s\cdot V_s\in \mathbb R$...). Finally, the proof is very well known whenever $M$ is a Brownian motion. So, first, see what happen whenever $M$ is a Brownian motion and $n=1$, then it shouldn't be hard to generalize ;-)

Comment: @Surb Thank you for your reply. I have revised and hope it is more clear now. Would you please give a reference to this proof or just Brownian motion case. I am new to this topic and find it really confused to me.

Comment: More or less all books os stochastic calculs...

Comment: @Surb Hi, I have found a similar statement in Karatzas's book (Ch 3.2), where we need $\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\int_{0}^{t} V_{s}^{2} d\left\langle M^{c}\right\rangle_{s}\right)\right]<\infty$. How would our $\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\int_{0}^{t} V_{s}^{2} d\left\langle M^{c}\right\rangle_{s}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right]<\infty $ imply that