# What is the expectation of the Ito integral $\int_0^tg^2(\tau)dW_\tau$?

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, expected-value, stochastic-calculus, finance

I am having some trouble working out $E\left[ \int_0^tg^2(\tau)dW_\tau \right]$. I don't even really know where to begin, I'm very new to Ito Calculus and any help or nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is $g$ deterministic, or another random process?  Either way, it's probably useful to know that Ito integrals are local martingales.

Comment: It might be useful to read: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232932/it%C5%8D-integral-has-expectation-zero